# Avoid using START WITH.. CONNECT BY PRIOR

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which is calling a function in `WHERE` clause like

`SELECT * FROM table_name t WHERE (SELECT xyz_function(t.test) FROM dual) = 'A';`

And a function xyz_function which is returning 'A' or 'B' depending on the below condition :

```
SELECT 'A' FROM dual WHERE pTest NOT IN (
                                         a_START_WITH_CONNECT_BY_CLAUSE
                                         MINUS
                                         b_START_WITH_CONNECT_BY_CLAUSE);
```

Here `pTest` is the parameter that I am passing to the function.
I am using two `START WITH.. CONNECT BY PRIOR` clause in the function.

Since the function is called in WHERE clause.. it is getting executed for all the t.test.

The query is giving almost 20K records and hence timing out.

It seems that the query is timing out because of the `START WITH.. CONNECT BY` clause in the function.

Can anyone help me removing the START WITH.. CONNECT WITH clause..?

Comment: Can you please post the query you're currently running; it'll be difficult to emulate the same behavior without knowing what has to be emulated. Equally, it would be helpful if you could post your table definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Would...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    table_name t 
WHERE 
    t.test NOT IN 
    (
        a_START_WITH_CONNECT_BY_CLAUSE
        MINUS
        b_START_WITH_CONNECT_BY_CLAUSE
    );
```

...be equivalent to what you have currently?  It's hard to say without seeing what your tables, function, and CONNECT BY clauses look like.  However, if it is equivalent, you might get better performance, because the MINUS query might not need to be evaluated on every row.

Comment: This approach would likely perform much better because it avoids the overhead of the SQL-PLSQL context switch from calling the function.

Comment: [According to Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602) the context switch only accounts for around 1/1000s @LordPeter so _much_ better is a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: @Ben in this case you are absolutely correct - it doesn't look as though the function is likely to be called more than once/twice. However, I have come across functions being called for 100,000s of rows which can kill performance. Just wanted to emphasize that a pure SQL approach is almost always preferable. (+1 for link to AskTom)